# Save and load asymmetric keys from jPBC

Tags: java, encryption, serialization, encoding, jpbc

I want similar functionality as prescribe [Easy way to store/restore encryption key for decrypting string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925104/easy-way-to-store-restore-encryption-key-for-decrypting-string-in-java)

But my case is different. In the above link they are using `javax.crypto.*` but in my case I am using `org.bouncycastle.crypto.*` and `it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghsw13.generators.*`

I want to store master-secret-key, public-key and private-key in different files and also retrieve those keys from files. How to do it ?

Below is the code where I left *TODO*s. Working code can be found on [github](https://github.com/junaidbinsarfraz/ABE).

```
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.circuit.BooleanCircuit;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.circuit.BooleanCircuit.BooleanCircuitGate;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghsw13.engines.GGHSW13KEMEngine;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghsw13.generators.GGHSW13KeyPairGenerator;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghsw13.generators.GGHSW13ParametersGenerator;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghsw13.generators.GGHSW13SecretKeyGenerator;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghsw13.params.*;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.kem.cipher.engines.KEMCipher;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.kem.cipher.params.KEMCipherDecryptionParameters;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.kem.cipher.params.KEMCipherEncryptionParameters;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.pairing.PairingFactory;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.util.concurrent.ExecutorServiceUtils;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.circuit.Gate.Type.*;

public class Example {
    protected KEMCipher kemCipher;
    protected AlgorithmParameterSpec iv;

    protected AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;


    public Example() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        this.kemCipher = new KEMCipher(
                Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BC"),
                new GGHSW13KEMEngine()
        );

        // build the initialization vector.  This example is all zeros, but it
        // could be any value or generated using a random number generator.
        iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
    }


    public AsymmetricCipherKeyPair setup(int n) {
        GGHSW13KeyPairGenerator setup = new GGHSW13KeyPairGenerator();
        setup.init(new GGHSW13KeyPairGenerationParameters(
                new SecureRandom(),
                new GGHSW13ParametersGenerator().init(
                        PairingFactory.getPairing("params/mm/ctl13/toy.properties"),
                        n).generateParameters()
        ));

        return (keyPair = setup.generateKeyPair());
    }


    public byte[] initEncryption(String assignment) {
        try {
            return kemCipher.init(
                    true,
                    new KEMCipherEncryptionParameters(
                            128,
                            new GGHSW13EncryptionParameters(
                                    (GGHSW13PublicKeyParameters) keyPair.getPublic(),
                                    assignment
                            )
                    ),
                    iv
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String message) {
        try {
            return kemCipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public CipherParameters keyGen(BooleanCircuit circuit) {
        GGHSW13SecretKeyGenerator keyGen = new GGHSW13SecretKeyGenerator();
        keyGen.init(new GGHSW13SecretKeyGenerationParameters(
                ((GGHSW13PublicKeyParameters) keyPair.getPublic()),
                ((GGHSW13MasterSecretKeyParameters) keyPair.getPrivate()),
                circuit
        ));

        return keyGen.generateKey();
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(CipherParameters secretKey, byte[] encapsulation, byte[] ciphertext) {
        try {
            kemCipher.init(
                    false,
                    new KEMCipherDecryptionParameters(secretKey, encapsulation, 128),
                    iv
            );
            return kemCipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        try {
            // Setup
            int n = 4;
            Example engine = new Example();
            engine.setup(n);

            // TODO: Here I want to store (GGHSW13PublicKeyParameters) keyPair.getPublic() and 
            // (GGHSW13MasterSecretKeyParameters) keyPair.getPrivate() in files and later to retrieve from file

            // Encrypt
            String message = "Hello World!!!";
            byte[] encapsulation = engine.initEncryption("1101");
            byte[] ciphertext = engine.encrypt(message);

            BooleanCircuitGate bcg1 = new BooleanCircuitGate(INPUT, 0, 1);

            BooleanCircuitGate[] bcgs = new BooleanCircuitGate[]{
                    new BooleanCircuitGate(INPUT, 0, 1),
                    new BooleanCircuitGate(INPUT, 1, 1),
                    new BooleanCircuitGate(INPUT, 2, 1),
                    new BooleanCircuitGate(INPUT, 3, 1),

                    new BooleanCircuitGate(AND, 4, 2, new int[]{0, 1}),
                    new BooleanCircuitGate(OR, 5, 2, new int[]{2, 3}),

                    new BooleanCircuitGate(AND, 6, 3, new int[]{4, 5}),
            };

            List<BooleanCircuitGate> bcgList = new ArrayList<BooleanCircuitGate>();

            bcgList.add(bcg1);
            bcgList.add(new BooleanCircuitGate(INPUT, 1, 1));
            bcgList.add(new BooleanCircuitGate(INPUT, 2, 1));
            bcgList.add(new BooleanCircuitGate(INPUT, 3, 1));
            bcgList.add(new BooleanCircuitGate(AND, 4, 2, new int[]{0, 1}));
            bcgList.add(new BooleanCircuitGate(OR, 5, 2, new int[]{2, 3}));
            bcgList.add(new BooleanCircuitGate(AND, 6, 3, new int[]{4, 5}));

            // Decrypt
            int q = 3;
            BooleanCircuit circuit = new BooleanCircuit(n, q, 3, bcgList.toArray(new BooleanCircuitGate[bcgList.size()]));

            GGHSW13SecretKeyParameters secretKey = (GGHSW13SecretKeyParameters) engine.keyGen(circuit);

            // TODO: Want to store secretKey in file and later to retrieve from file

            byte[] plaintext = engine.decrypt(secretKey, encapsulation, ciphertext);

            System.out.println(new String(plaintext));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ExecutorServiceUtils.shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: so do you have a question?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I want to store master-secret-key, public-key and private-key in different files and also retrieve those keys from files.

Comment: so you want to know how to read data from a file?

Comment: Nope, I want to know that how to save encryption keys in files and how to read those keys from file. In simple words I want to know that how to store keys in file and load keys from file.

Comment: you would save the key in a keystore

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890313/how-to-use-keystore-in-java-to-store-private-key

Comment: Well I am not sure if I can and I have to use keystore for this purpose. The link you shared is using `java.security.KeyPairGenerator` whereas I used `org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair`. Can you come-up with an example that how can I use *keystore* to store keys (`org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair`) ?

Comment: read http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/docs/pg.html#.WPb3dFV97cs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142037/discussion-between-junaid-and-scary-wombat).

Comment: @ScaryWombat jPBC doesn't integrate into JCE, so normal JCE-type serializations don't apply here.

Comment: @ArtjomB. you are right. Is there any solution/work-around you know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you generate your master key and the public parameters, you should store them so that you can actually use them later on. jPBC doesn't provide you with a way to store these keys. Also, since the keys inherit from `org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter`, you can't use Java's serialization, because `AsymmetricKeyParameter` does not implement the `Serializable` interface. It [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14134628/1816580) work without.

You will need to implement the serialization yourself. First, you have to think about what kind of objects are inside of a key that you want to serialize. In the case of the `GGHSW13MasterSecretKeyParameters` class, this is an `Element`, an `int` and a `Pairing`.

First, you have to think about whether you want to include the `Pairing` in the serialized key. If you do, you must write it into the beginning in order to be able to use it later for deserializing the `Element`.

If we assume that a `Pairing` instance is constant or is always provided from outer code, the serialization is pretty easy. You should write a format version to the front, so you can change your formats along the way without throwing away all your previously serialized keys. Writing the element is a little more tricky, because of a bug I encountered 2 years ago. The basic idea is that you write the length of the element's bytes followed by the element's content.

```
public void serialize(GGHSW13MasterSecretKeyParameters msk, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(out);

    dOut.writeInt(1); // version of the serialized format
    dOut.writeInt(msk.getParameters().getN());

    serialize(msk.getAlpha(), dOut, msk.getParameters().getPairing());
}

public void serialize(Element elem, DataOutputStream dOut, Pairing pairing) throws IOException {
    dOut.writeBoolean(elem == null);
    if (elem == null) {
        return;
    }

    dOut.writeInt(pairing.getFieldIndex(elem.getField()));
    byte[] bytes = elem.toBytes();
    dOut.writeInt(bytes.length);
    dOut.write(bytes);

    // this is a workaround because it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.field.curve.CurveElement does not serialize the infFlag
    dOut.writeBoolean(elem instanceof CurveElement && elem.isZero());
    if (elem instanceof CurveElement && elem.isZero()) {
        throw new IOException("Infinite element detected. They should not happen.");
    }
}
```

The `OutputStream` can be something like `FileOutputSteam` or `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

The deserialization is equally easy, but you need to explicitly supply the `Pairing` and you need to make sure that you always read *exactly* as many bytes as you requested. The number of bytes that you request is known from the length int that is written in front of the data. If you don't make a check whether that length makes sense, you might introduce a security issue such as a denial of service vulnerability or remote code execution.

```
public GGHSW13MasterSecretKeyParameters deserialize(InputStream in, Pairing pairing) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(in);

    int version = dIn.readInt();
    if (version != 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown key format version: " + version);
    }

    int n = dIn.getInt();
    Element alpha = deserialize(dIn, pairing);

    return new GGHSW13MasterSecretKeyParameters(
            new GGHSW13Parameters(pairing, n),
            alpha
    );
}

public Element deserialize(DataInputStream dIn, Pairing pairing) throws IOException {
    if (dIn.readBoolean()) {
        return null;
    }

    int fieldIndex = dIn.readInt(); // TODO: check if this is in a sensible range
    int length = dIn.readInt(); // TODO: check if this is in a sensible range
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    dIn.readFully(bytes); // throws an exception if there is a premature EOF
    Element e = pairing.getFieldAt(fieldIndex).newElementFromBytes(bytes);

    // this is a workaround because it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.field.curve.CurveElement does not serialize the infFlag
    boolean instOfCurveElementAndInf = dIn.readBoolean();
    if (instOfCurveElementAndInf) {
        //e.setToZero(); // according to the code this simply sets the infFlag to 1
        throw new IOException("The point is infinite. This shouldn't happen.");
    }
    return e;
}
```

This is a binary serialization which is sort of small. There are other possibilities like encoding all the components to a string and using JSON for example.

Comment: This code is untested. If you see typos please edit the code or post a comment.

Comment: Brilliant solution with good description. Till now I am able to store and load *master-secret-key* and *public-key*. You can find it here https://github.com/junaidbinsarfraz/ABE . Now can you please help me to store and load *secret-key* because this involves `BooleanCricuit` and `BooleanCricuit` involve `AND`, `OR`, `NAND` and `INPUT` `Type`s ?

Comment: The same techniques would apply, but you have to traverse through the circuit recursively probably storing your own references. Anyway, that's out of scope for this question.

Comment: I asked in the question for *private-key* too. I am having hard time with the `Type`s like `AND`, `OR`, `NAND` and `INPUT`. I couldn't get that how to would I be able to `serialize` and `deserialize` the `BooleanGate` ?

Comment: Right, not enough hours in the day for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. I use the JPBC to realize the server and client mode. From the client side, the client should use JPBC to encrypt the plaintext, and the server should decrypt the cipertext to recover the plaintext. My question is what message should I send from the client to server so that the server can decrypt the cipertext, that is, I can serialize the keys including the public key and private key but how can I serialize the ***pairing*** because I should use the same pairing in the server side.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be great if you can post a separate question and put a link of this question for reference.