# Not Serialized services fields

Tags: java

I have a Class that i want to serialize so I can store it in the Database, but some of the fields which are the Services doesn't need to be serialized, how can achieved that?

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private SampleClass sampleClass;

    private MyService myService;

    private OtherService otherService;

    ....

}
```

Because it throwing a:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException:
```

Comment: Mark it `transient`?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/95208/2310289

Comment: *i want to serialize so I can store it in the Database* ?

Comment: Note that anything you don't store in the database, you also won't retrieve from the database, either.

Comment: I would not recommend serializing types referencing services. You should separate the services from the data e.g. with so called entities and serialize them.

Answer (score 0):

In your POJO class if you want any field need not to be serialized then you need to ignore that field at serialization time.

For example in your case if you want to ignore service then you can go through below code :

```
@JsonIgnore
private MyService myService;

@JsonIgnore
private OtherService otherService;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the fields with the `transient` keyword. It will cause the default serialization mechanism to skip the marked fields.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private transient SampleClass sampleClass;
    private transient MyService myService;
    private transient OtherService otherService;

    private AnotherSerializableClass serializableField;
    //AnotherSerializableClass must implement Serializable
}
```

You will also need a way to restore the services when you deserialize an object - via setters for example.

Comment: how about the fields that i want to include in the serialization. I need to modify the class and implement serializable? is there any other shortcut to do that? Because there is a lot of child child fields

Comment: @rlchaps26 The fields that have to be serialized need to implement `Serializable`, no way around that, if you want to use the serialization mechanism of java. If you don't want to modify existing classes, then you need another serialization mechanism, in this case [How to Serialize/Deserialize an object without implementing Serializable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134628/how-to-serialize-deserialize-an-object-without-implementing-serializable-interfa) may help.

Comment: do you think which is more efficient storing to the DB, JSON or bytes?

Comment: @rlchaps26 Highly likely the binary format, but you have to measure it yourself to be certain. Json is human readable on the other hand, pick format depending on your needs.

Comment: the only problem i have is in a certain class there is a lot of fields and child child fields that has a lot of object also inside. Like database initialization, so its hard to put `implements Serializable` and `transient`